What is the position directly below the moon on the earth called - is it the lunar nadir?
What is the position directly below the moon on the Earth called - is it the lunar nadir or something else ?

Wouldn't that be sublunar, similar to subsolar? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsolar_point

I believe it's "selenographic position of Earth".  But there is probably more than one term.

I misread the question, what I was referring to above is the position on the Moon which Earth is directly below.  The position on Earth the Moon is above is called the "geographic position" (or simply GP) of the Moon.

@Greg Miller I use "GP" all the time, too. And I also feel there must be some other terms.

FWIW, Horizons can calculate such points. https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons/manual.html#obsquan See 14. Observer sub-longitude & sub-latitude

Both Oxford dictionary and the Merriem-Webster dictionary have sublunar point, just like @asdfex has suggested.
https://www.oxfordreference.com/display/10.1093/oi/authority.20110803100539770
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sublunar%20point
